# Uncaught ReferenceError: _asyncToGenerator is not defined

Tags: reactjs

I've faced the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: _asyncToGenerator is not defined" while building my React project.
I tried some research and it seems mainly related to babel configuration.
So I followed what they suggested but still no news.

Here's the code block.

```
function _init() {
    _init = _asyncToGenerator( /*#__PURE__*/_regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee(data) {
      var code, wasmModule;
      return _regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
        while (1) {
          switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
            case 0:
              code = new Uint8Array(data.code);
              _context.next = 3;
              return WebAssembly.compile(code);

            case 3:
              wasmModule = _context.sent;
              memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({
                initial: data.init
              });
              i32 = new Uint32Array(memory.buffer);
              _context.next = 8;
              return WebAssembly.instantiate(wasmModule, {
                env: {
                  "memory": memory
                }
              });

            case 8:
              instance = _context.sent;

            case 9:
            case "end":
              return _context.stop();
          }
        }
      }, _callee);
    }));
    return _init.apply(this, arguments);
  }
```

And here's my babel configuration.

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-class-properties",
    ["transform-runtime", {
      "polyfill": false,
      "regenerator": true
    }]
  ]
}
```

The project works well with 'npm start' but produce errors while I am trying to build.

Thanks